# Basic MVC (button to send e-mail) - ActionLink?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a 'mail server configuration' kind of view. On this view are 2 buttons:

```
[SOME FORM FIELDS]
<input class="button" type="submit" value="@T("Save")" />
<input class="button" type="submit" value="@T("Send Test Email")" />
```

The first button calls off to my controller and returns the same view with any validation/success messages (this is a form):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MailServerSettingsViewModel viewModel)
{
    ...
```

That works brilliantly, but obviously the 'Send Test Email' button will do the same.

Assuming I don't want to come away from the page (i.e. load a different view), but want to call off to another controller to send a test e-mail, is the 'proper' way to do this to use the `ActionLink` helper? From this other controller can I then return this same form view? Or can I somehow use the same controller but determine which button was pressed to decide whether to validate the view model or just call off to another service/class/whatever to send the test e-mail and responding appropriately?

You can probably tell from the way I'm asking this that I come from a WebForms background and it's still a case of me getting used to what's what with MVC.

**What I've Tried**

For now, I'm actually calling off to this other controller asynchronously with AJAX. It actually works well, and is probably most appropriate, but this won't always be the case so I want to know how I'd achieve the above for other scenarios.

Comment: You can use use ajax to test mail.

Comment: I know I can, I am doing that already. I'm asking how I would do this without AJAX. I mentioned AJAX for the sake of showing the fact I've already had a go myself at solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want ajax you can start a thread to send the email in your controller.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Send Test Email", 
                 "actionName", "ControllerName", 
                  new { MailServerSettingsViewModel }, new { @class = "button" })
```

Comment: I may not have asked this question correctly because it seems to be throwing a few people off; if this was in webforms, I'd wire up an event handler, so that 'Save' attempted to save the newly entered date and validate the form in the process. 'Send Test Email' would send a test e-mail in an entirely different 'Click' event handler. What is the MVC alternative?

Comment: Forget about webforms you will get confused, in MVC it will be an action no such things as events

Comment: I know, but I'm asking (in a nutshell) how I'd have two buttons doing entirely different things in one view, both to display the same view after they're finished.

Comment: @DeeMac I know what you are asking you would use `@Html.ActionLink`

Comment: Thanks very much. So (last question) - am I right in saying that an ActionLink serves as a sort of override to a form's action? It'll prioritise it's own action as opposed to simply submitting the form to the form's action? Thanks again.

Comment: yes because It creates a link to a controller action

Comment: I'm not an ASP MVC expert, but I thought ActionLink() was just a convenience for producing <a> tags.  Eg: it generates the href attribute for you using the controller name, action method name, etc.

Comment: @Twicetimes he wants two buttons doing different things, this will be 2 different links calling different action in the same controllers. as opposed to have different forms

Comment: @meda Exactly, they would be 2 links, not form-submission buttons (unless you linked to the form action, doing a GET, or used javascript, which isn't what he wants to understand).

Comment: @DeeMac I added an example how you can call an action from any controller

Answer (score 1):

If you set the 'name' attribute on both submit buttons to the same value, you can detect which was clicked in your controller by inspecting the value.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know you could do this. Isn't this then kind of moving back towards a similar sort of control event handling context of webforms though? I thought the distinction in functionality should be made using distinct actions?

Comment: It's just how form submissions have always worked.  Clicking 'submit' sends all the input values in the form to the address in the form's 'action' attribute.  Different intended actions can only be indicated by using differently named submit buttons (or separate forms, which often isn't practical).